# R Subsetting an Age Bracket?

Tags: r

I want to subset a data frame by age group.

Only those obs where:

> age > 35 and age < 80

My attempts didn't give what I wanted.

It gave me rows below 35 and above 80 for age.

```
subset(data,age > 35 & age < 80,select = myvar)
```

I tried `&&`, but that didn't work either.

Does this have to be done in two steps?

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes sample code sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`) and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Provided that `data` contains columns `age`, `myvar` with values in the expected range, I cannot see why that code example would not work as expected.

Comment: This works: `subset(data.frame(age=c(1,30,50,80,100), myvar=letters[1:5]), age > 35 & age < 80, select = myvar)` (which is just your subsetting/selecting with known data).

Comment: Yes, I tried this on a simple dataset and it works! Not sure whats wrong with my dataset, it's from nhanes. If I figure it out, I'll post the problem, thanks Bob I thought it was my code.

Comment: Well, the problem was the age variable is character not numeric. I should have noticed when one of the entries was "80 years of age and older", but I'm new to this type of dataset. Sorry for the confusion. Bob

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use **subset()** try something like this:

```
person <- c("John", "Jane", "Bill", "Betty", "Cindy")
age <- c(10, 40, 50, 90, 100)
data <- data.frame(person, age)
age35_80 <- data[data$age > 35 & data$age < 80,]
```

Only need to use a single **&** to vectorize.